# Using node.js in Apigee, how do I determine what environment I am running in prod or test?

Tags: apigee

I've tried setting as environment variable like this:

```
<EnvironmentVariable name="APIGEE_ENV" ref="environment.name" />
```

or

```
<EnvironmentVariable name="APIGEE_ENV">{environment.name}</EnvironmentVariable>
```

but neither of these have returned anything?

This is important because I would like my 'test' environment to hit my dev API server and 'prod' to hit my production API server.

Comment: I'm actually not sure off hand how you're supposed to do this, but could you grab it out of the URL subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue is getting the environment.name variable into the parameter, one way to solve this would be to use separate targets for each:

```
<TargetEndpoint name="testTarget">
  <ScriptTarget>
     <ResourceURL>node://mynode.js</ResourceURL>
     <EnvironmentVariables>
         <EnvironmentVariable name="APIGEE_ENV">test</EnvironmentVariable> 
     </EnvironmentVariables>
  </ScriptTarget>
</TargetEndpoint>

<TargetEndpoint name="prodTarget">
  <ScriptTarget>
     <ResourceURL>node://mynode.js</ResourceURL>
     <EnvironmentVariables>
         <EnvironmentVariable name="APIGEE_ENV">prod</EnvironmentVariable> 
     </EnvironmentVariables>
  </ScriptTarget>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

and then use the environment name in the RouteRules (bottom of the proxy file) to select the correct target:

```
<RouteRule name="prod">
  <Condition>environment.name == "prod"</Condition>
  <TargetEndpoint>prodTarget</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule
<RouteRule name="test">
  <TargetEndpoint>testTarget</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule
```

Comment: This almost works.  I had to copy the script so that the two targets didn't point to the same file.  I'm not sure how this actually spins up on the backend, but it seems that whichever one spins up first the two environments would share it unless they were pointing at different scripts.